# Recommended method of starting a scheduled activity on start up?

Tags: android, service, android-activity, broadcastreceiver

Im trying to make an scheduled activity go off every hour or so, all working in the background.

Right now i have a BroadcastReceiver that picks up when the device is booted.
The BroadcastReceiver creates a PendingIntent to an activity (Called AlarmController) that creates has all necessary methods that i need for making the scheduled activity to go off.

How ever, this doesnt seem to work.
This is how my BroadcastReciever class onReceive{} looks like **and** is indentical to my main activity onCreate{}(Only for testing)

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(serviceactivirt.this, AlarmController.class);
    PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getActivity(serviceactivirt.this, 0, intent, 0);
    try {
        sender.send();
    } catch (CanceledException e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "FEJLSAN", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

This actually works, except that my app crashes at launch, but the scheduled activity is working...
Any ideas? Is this "The way to do it" or is there a more recommended way? 
Cheers!

Solution:

Instead of having a BroadcastReciever calling an Activity, i made the BroadcastReciever starting a Service. And changed my Activity to a Service, programmaticly and in manifest.
Works great!

Comment: why is the activity crashing?

Answer (score 0):

> Im trying to make an scheduled activity go off every hour or so, all working in the background.

Please allow users to configure other options, such as using a `Notification`, rather than being interrupted by an activity taking over the foreground.

> Right now i have a BroadcastReceiver that picks up when the device is booted.

You would only need that to set up an `AlarmManager` schedule for your hourly events. Your `PendingIntent` for the `AlarmManager` could be one you obtain via `getActivity()`.

> How ever, this doesnt seem to work.

If you want to start an activity, call `startActivity()`. Do not create a `PendingIntent`, then immediately `send()` the `PendingIntent`.

Also, get rid of `getApplicationContext()` and simply use `this`.

> except that my app crashes at launch

Use `adb logcat`, DDMS, or the DDMS perspective in Eclipse to examine LogCat and look at the stack trace associated with your crash.